# Cannot get autoincrement value, Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3.2

I getting this error inside /var/log/system.log on instalation succesfully finished, but with error. My admin site not function, sample data either:

```
[2019-08-05 16:41:20] main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []
[2019-08-05 16:44:12] main.INFO: Reference to undeclared plugin with name 'stockedProductsFilterPlugin'. [] []
[2019-08-05 16:46:26] main.ERROR: Sample Data error: Cannot get autoincrement value [] []
```

are you someone able to advice me what I made wrong?
I set values as recomanded from Magento 2:

```
php.ini
my.ini
```

using windows 10, apache 2, php 7.2.2, mysql server 8.0, Magento-CE-2.3.2_sample_data

Comment: did you create or use custom module? If so, is your UpgradeSchema.php script create the tables using the correct way?

Comment: no did not @RendyEkoPrastiyo